# Which of the given spaces are homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

In which of the following two cases, $X$ is homeomorphic to $Y$?

1. $X = \{(x, y, z)\in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2+y^2=1\}, \ Y = \{(x, y, z)\in \mathbb{R}^3: z=0, x^2+y^2\neq 0\}$
2. $X = \{(x, y, z)\in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2+y^2=1\}, \ Y = \{(x, y, z)\in \mathbb{R}^3:  x^2+y^2=z^2\neq 0\}$

I am able to get the $X$ is an infinite cylinder in both the options. $Y$ in the first option is complete xy plane except $(0, 0, 0)$. So, how to look further?

Comment: For 1: Can you show that both $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic to $S^1 \times \mathbb R$ (this implies in particular that $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic to each other) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of the second option, $X$ and $Y$ are not homeomorphic, since $X$ is connected, whereas $Y$ isn't.

On the other hand, in the case of the first option, we *do* have a homeomorphism:$$\begin{array}{ccc}X&\longrightarrow&Y\\(x,y,z)&\mapsto&e^z(x,y,0).\end{array}$$

Comment: A decomposition of $Y$ in $(2)$ into two disjoint, open, non-empty subspaces is given by $Y = (Y \cap \{ z < 0 \} ) \dot \cup (Y \cap \{ z > 0\})$

Comment: Exactly @Berni Waterman. So the points on the upper half space cannot  be connected to the lower half space.

Comment: And further, $Y$ in #2 is homeomorphic to two disjoint copies of $Y$ in #1, @BerniWaterman